# what is Substrate Files Decentralised storage?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

Can anyone please give me any link or docs where I can find more about **Substrate Files decentralized storage**?

I have gone through this link: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/6106

Is there any other material to explore more about it?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there was an announcement by the Crust team when this feature came out:

> Polkadot Files module is now LIVE for all Polkadot ecosystem users,
> including relay and parachain users  @Polkadot
>
> ✅File storage
>
> ✅NFT metadata pinning
>
> ✅Website hosting
>
> ✅DECENTRALIZED
> through #CrustNetwork and #IPFS!

- https://twitter.com/CrustNetwork/status/1494263644229861377?s=20&t=E1W6Hj7u8wxWkf3WOkCEVg

That [link](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/6106) that you shared pretty much has all the information.

For example, the README states:

> Substrate Files is a decentralized storage module which allows
> substrate-based chains(including
> Polkadot/Kusama/Crust/Acala/Clover/Moonbeam/Astar/Phala/...) users
> upload their files to IPFS W3Auth Gateway and decentralized pin their
> files on Crust Network by using the standard IPFS W3Auth Pinning
> Service. This module is a 100% IPFS compatible file storage module,
> users can pin NFT files, host DApps or store on-chain data in totally
> DECENTRALIZED way(guaranteed by Crust protocol). Also, the Pinning
> Service is compatible with several Platforms like Ethereum, Polygon,
> Solana and Near, and funded by Decentralized Cloud Foundation. So
> currently, Substrate Files is FREE for all the substrate-based chains!

- https://github.com/crustio/apps/blob/b1fe7a10b6e7e67ad926842edab598bdc3474717/packages/page-files/README.md

You can read about the particulars by reading [the code](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/6106/files) and the Crust technology that was used e.g. [IPFS W3Auth Gateway](https://wiki.crust.network/docs/en/buildIPFSWeb3AuthGW)

If you're not familiar with how Crust works, start here:

- https://wiki.crust.network/docs/en/crustOverview